# .sh file works in terminal but not in python script (rclone w/ Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python-2.7, shell, raspberry-pi

I'm having trouble running a .sh file in python.  When I type in the location of the .sh file (/home/pi/file/script.sh) the script runs perfectly.

I'm trying to run this script in my python2 script and I've done the following methods:

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'location of .sh'])
subprocess.call(['location of .sh'])
os.popen(['location of .sh'])
```

When I run the python script, I get a prompt from rclone saying "Command sync needs 2 arguments maximum"

My .sh file just includes:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/local/bin/rclone -v sync /home/pi/some_project_data remote:rclone --delete-before --include *.csv --include *.py
```

I'm not sure how running the .sh file on terminal works fine, but this error pops up when I'm trying to run the .sh file using Python.

Comment: And what *is* the `.sh` file? Or at least the part that fails. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just edited question @Daniel H

Answer (score 1):

Your script fails whenever you run it in a directory containing 2 or more `.csv` or `.py` files. This is true for terminals as well as via Python.

To avoid that, quote your patterns so the shell doesn't expand them:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/local/bin/rclone -v sync /home/pi/some_project_data remote:rclone \
                           --delete-before --include "*.csv" --include "*.py"
```

Comment: This seems to fix one problem but another arises... It reads: "Config file "/root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found -using defaults then \\\   Failed to create file system for "remote:rclone": didn't find section in config file

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
os.popen('bash locationof.sh')
```

ex:

```
os.popen('bash /home/script.sh')
```

That worked on my machine. If you place square brackets around the string then python assumes it is a list and popen doesnt accept a list, it accepts a single string.

If the script doesnt work, then this won't fix that, but it will at least run it. If it still doesnt work, try running the script with something like

```
touch z.txt
```

and see if z.txt appears in the file explorer. If it does, then your .sh file has a problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately.  When I run the command in command prompt, it is successful (basically the code that I put in the .sh file).  But when I do ./script.sh it turns up the same prompt and doesn't sync

Comment: Are you using the prefix "bash" or "./" ?  Using "./" can incur permission problems and you should use "bash". Try that and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried bash as well and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried going to your terminal and typing python2 followed by import os and then os.popen('bash /home/script.sh') ? (Put your own file path as a replacement for /home/script.sh). Then if it doesnt work, post the error message.

Comment: It reads: "Config file "/root/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found -using defaults then \\\ Failed to create file system for "remote:rclone": didn't find section in config file.